# Parse error passing search criteria to imaplib

Tags: python, imaplib

This may be a newbie question, but I can't figure out why I can't successfully pass parameterized search criteria to imaplib.

Setup code is:

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
M.login("usrname", "passwd") 
typ, data = self.M.select()   # Select default mailbox
```

The following works:

```
typ, data = M.uid('search', None, '(SENTSINCE 01-Jan-2010)')
```

But if I try to pass the search criteria as a string I get

```
imaplib.error: UID command error: BAD ['Could not parse command']
```

This is the code that fails:

```
f = "'(SENTSINCE 01-Jan-1994)'"
typ, data = M.uid('search', None, f)
```

I've tried numerous syntax, read RFC3501. Is this a charset problem?

Comment: try to remove one set of quotes in your string `f`

Comment: Yup - that did it I'm embarrassed to say.. imaplib and gmail are very particular about syntax for criterion and I had two other problems in my actual code (a superfluous space and missing quotes).  All three issues gave the BAD parse error but in none of my testing did I fix all three at the same time.  Would like to understand how the parentheses work in this situation so any pointers to the core docs on that would be appreciated.

Comment: please clarify this question, the original bug, and the actual answer as an answer.  i am having a similar problem and have been searching for an answer for many months...

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the date within quotes and your code for that will be :

```
typ, data = M.uid('search', None, '(SENTSINCE "01-Jan-2010")')
```